# Upgrade problem from 2.4.2-p1 to 2.4.3-p2

Tags: composer, magento2.4.3

When I try and upgrade from 2.4.2-p1 to 2.4.3-p2 these are the steps I follow-

composer require magento/product-enterprise-edition:2.4.3-p2 --no-update

composer update magento/product-enterprise-edition:2.4.3-p2 --ignore-platform-reqs

When I do I get this set of errors-

```
  Problem 1
    - The requested package magento/product-enterprise-edition (locked at 2.4.2-p1, required as 2.4.3-p2) is satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.4.2-p1] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
 Problem 2
- Can only install one of: magento/product-community-edition[2.4.3-p2, 2.4.2-p1].
- Can only install one of: magento/product-community-edition[2.4.2-p1, 2.4.3-p2].
- Can only install one of: magento/product-community-edition[2.4.3-p2, 2.4.2-p1].
- magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.4.3-p2 requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.3-p2 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.3-p2].
- Installation request for magento/product-enterprise-edition 2.4.3-p2 -> satisfiable by magento/product-enterprise-edition[2.4.3-p2].
- Installation request for magento/product-community-edition (locked at 2.4.2-p1) -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.2-p1]
```

My stability is set to stable so I don't think that is a problem. What else could it be? I can update extensions through composer with no problem so I don't think it is a composer problem.

Edit-https://imgur.com/0uyK93F

Comment: you can upgrade magento enterprise edition upgrade OR community edition ?

Comment: I am on enterprise, nothing to do with community which makes that weird.

Answer (score 0):

- Edit your composer.json file and replace 2.4.2-p1 to 2.4.3-p2
- run "composer update" command

Comment: I added a screenshot of the require section. It does not say 2.4.2-p1 in there at all.

Comment: @tigen, can you try deleting the composer.lock file and the vendor folder and then hit "composer update" command?